# JavaScript - Reinvoke submit event works on Chrome but does not work on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, devexpress

I have an ASP.Net web site and I need to get geolocation data in any postback.

I want to catch the submit event and re-raise it after getting geolocation data, calling to `form1.submit();` does not work because the buttons in the page are DevExpress Buttons and they are implement the click event and postback by themselves.

I tried to find the root caller and recall it as the follows, this works good on Chrome but does not work on Firefox, Firefox call to the root caller again but the submit event does not occur.

```
    function beforeSubmit(e) {
        var latField = document.getElementById('lat');
        var lngField = document.getElementById('lng');
        var clickFunction = getRootCaller();

        if (latField.value == '' || lngField.value == '') {
            GetGeolocation(function (latitude, longitude) {
                latField.value = latitude;
                lngField.value = longitude;
                clickFunction();
            },
            function () {
                latField.value = 'missing lat';
                lngField.value = 'missing lng';
                clickFunction();
            })
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    function getRootCaller() {
        var thisFunction = arguments.callee;
        var caller = thisFunction.caller;
        while (caller.caller != null) {
            caller = caller.caller;
        }
        return caller;
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var formClientID = '<%= Page.Form.ClientID %>';
        $(document.getElementById(formClientID)).submit(beforeSubmit);
    });
```

Comment: are there any error shown in the **Developer Tools _console_** ... at a guess I think you *may* need to call `e.preventDefault()` - but I'm not sure how jqueery queers the event argument

Comment: There are not errors in the **Developer Tools console**, the cancellation of the submit event is succeeded but the problem is when I try recall to the root caller

Comment: `the problem is` - try debugging, what does `getRootCaller` return ... what intermediate values does it have whiles it's trying to get to the root ... you also need to understand that the code in `getRootCaller` will fail spectacularly in all browsers that support "strict mode" if you enable "strict mode"

Comment: both Chrome and Firefox the `getRootCaller` really holds the root caller function but when the browser call it, the submit event occurs only in the Chrome but not in Firefox, I did not got an error message about "strict mode" in the **Developer Tools console**